# A very strange bug with Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In google maps api v3, the following line works:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.082243,24.302628);
```

But, the following doesn't:

```
var gpsPos = '50.082243,24.302628';
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(gpsPos);
```

How strange is that, or better yet, how to fix this?

---

Here's the full code:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=SK&callback=initialize";
   document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize(){
   var gpsPos = '50.082243,24.302628';
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(gpsPos);

   var myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      scaleControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("otvorena-aukcia-mapa"), myOptions);

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng, 
      map: map
   });
}
```

Comment: `50.082243,24.302628` is two floats, `'50.082243,24.302628'` is a string. Would that really work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#LatLng) you cannot pass a string at all.

You'd have to explicitly split out the two parts and pass them as numbers:

```
var gpsPos = '50.082243,24.302628';
var splitted = gpsPos.split(",");
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(splitted[0] - 0, splitted[1] - 0); 
// '- 0' will automatically make it a number
```